# how to choose columns by name in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, using

I have source data with 5 columns and my current method to print it is following

```
plot "data.txt" index "here" using 2:xticlabels(1) axes x1y1,\
"" index "here" using  4:xticlabels(1)  ,\
"" index "here" using  5:xticlabels(1) ,\
"" index "here" using  3:xticlabels(1)
```

but last two columns can be switched (input data are not always same), and I still have to print them in previous order. So, I need tool to choose collumns by names, not by numbers. Something like this "columnname":xticlabels(1).

Comment: Have you tried that?  What version of gnuplot are you using?  (it appears that using strings as columnheaders was implemented in gnuplot4.6 which is the current stable release series)

Comment: Yes, I have. I use version 4.4 this is the problem.